# VNC control for WPF application

Tags: wpf, vnc

I'm looking for a control that will allow me to host a VNC client session on a WPF window.  Initial Googling has yielded nothing for WPF, only WinForms, so if nobody can point me to a WPF control, I would appreciate any advice on using a WinForms VNC control in a WPF application.  That is, how can I host a VNC client session in a WPF application?

Comment: I would be interested in what VNC control you are going to use. I'm asking because I'm looking for one myself ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend going with the WinForms control in a WPF applications approach.  It's really pretty simple.

- Add WindowsFormsIntegration reference to your project
- Add a WinForms integration element in your XAML:

  ```
  <WindowsFormsHost Name="host"/>
  ```
- Add your WinForms control to that element in the code-behind:

  ```
  host.Child = new WinFormsControl();
  ```

Answer (score 2):

A WinForms Control hosted in WPF has a major drawback. DeveloperExpress documented the issue for their LayoutManager component like that: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7551

Here is a WPF Implementation of VNCSharp called VncSharpWpf: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/horus531/20110515/1305443108

Both implementations are not the fastest in comparison to (other) native implementations. If anyone finds a better one, I would appreciate to know.